# Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly completely broken, lightdm/xorg broken, network down

Tags: networking, upgrade, updates, xorg, lightdm

i am on the edge of giving up (on using ubuntu at all). I've been a happy user for many years but since i use ubuntu 16.04 there is nearly no boot, where not at least one error occurs. I accepted the fact, that i get a strange error on every boot "unattended upgrade". No matter on what machine i install ubuntu, no matter what i do, i get this error every single boot.

Then some months ago my notebook wasnt able to shutdown anymore, i had to press the power-button. It took me months to figure out, that the problem was a nfs mount i entered in /etc/fstab. After "switching" to autofs i could poweroff again - yipi!

Then i needed to work on my older dual-boot desktop machine again and first i made some updates (apt-get upgrade, apt autoremove and so on). After rebooting suddenly the displaymanager is completely broken (low graphics mode...). I tried to install gdm over lightdm (as it seems that crap keeps on messing up my system) but the network is gone.. what the heck? no network, no graphics, what happen in the upgrade?

I thought - oh no, maybe my hardware is damaged - shut down the computer and started it again with windows 10. No Problem, the system starts and is working as always, graphics okay, network up...

So, why do i open this thread?

Did ubuntu become completely broken? Is it still worth installing or should i honestly consider switching to debian or some other distribution, that simply works? If i sum it all up i would guess, that 5%-10% of the time, i want to work with my computer, i have to solve some nasty issue with ubuntu. It never stops, it gets worse and worse. I dont really trust in 17.10 to be better.

I know, open source and make it better and contribute and so on... bla bla, dont get me completely wrong, i AM grateful for ubuntu, ive been very happy with it for a long time now. The thing is - IMO it is getting worse with every release.

I would even dare to say, that - at this day - ubuntu can not be considered a productive operating system anymore :-(

To not violate all rules and still ask a question:

What update may caused my system to have broken graphics and networks?

The affected system has the following hardware specs:

- Phenom 2 X4
- 8GB DDR3
- AMD Radeon R9 380
- OS installed on SSD (Dual boot with win10, Bootloader=Grub)
- network via onboard chip (some Asus AM3 Mainboard)

Comment: `ifconfig -a` does not show any interface, only lo, `lshw -c  network` shows my ethernet controller (AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit / Qualcomm Atheros.

Comment: So, it seems no driver claimed the ethernet controller, its really rediculous, that ubuntu updates itself to a state, where the networking driver will be lost. So, what do i do now? no network and no usb stick available, so you are ... no good?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i managed to fix my computer.

1) My network was gone because the specific kernel did not contain the driver i needed (alx). I had to boot with an older kernel and update to a more recent version. For some strange reason 4.4.0-98-generic did not include it, 4.4.0-101-generic works though

2) I uninstalled xserver-xorg, deleted all .x* files belonging to it, made all updates, rebooted and my graphical interface works again.

Its very frustrating to poweron your computer to work just to see, that a kernel update made the pc completely unusable, new kernel patchlevel releases should never remove any drivers - especially on a lts version! Maybe i am wrong on this and something else caused my troubles, i dont know...